# Alternate a BASH variable by Date

Tags: bash

What method can one use to alternate a variable which is dependable by time?

For example, this week var = Office, then next week var = Oncall?

The resulting script will be using crontab to output the contents of var depending on which week it was.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it normal that there is 2 variables "var" and "vare1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date +%W` to check what week number of the year it is (starting Monday).

You can alternate between the two with e.g.

```
if (( $(date +%W) % 2 ))
then
  var=Office
else
  var=Oncall
fi
```

Comment: so basically this means, if the number of weeks is divisible by 2, then Office, otherwise Oncall (in other words, alternate weeks)? thx.